# Macbook Air 2012 memory upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, apple-store

I've won a 4gb RAM Macbook Air yesterday. 
I know that the RAM is soldered to the motherboard, so therefore non user upgradeable.

I was wondering whether my nearest Apple Store could perform an upgrade to 8gb RAM on site? Do they offer that kind of service?

Comment: Not of what I know.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, that is a nice price! Unfortunately the RAM is soldered to the logic board. So changing simple RAM DIMM's is not possible. The only way to upgrade your RAM is to swap the old logic board with a 8GB memory logic board. In most larger (official) Apple Stores there is the knowhow on how to swap logic boards. But I do not know the costs and I think it is not an economy wise decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade MacBook Air RAM, because you have to change the entire motherboard, and it isn't cheap.

I don't think that 4GB RAM are a problem, because if you can saturate 4GB RAM, and it's very hard if you don't do some rendering, system will swap on HD, and your HD is an SSD.
You can't appreciate the slow down.